"Push Notifications" toggle that can detect app's current authorization?
I'd like to add a versatile "Push Notifications" toggle to my SettingsView.
By versatile, I mean I'd like for the toggle to be automatically set to enabled if the app's notification current permission is authorized, provisional, or ephemeral. And disabled if denied or not determined.
Ideally, the toggle would also request permission if set to "not determined." And send to App Settings if set to "denied."
Snippet of my SettingsView
struct SettingsView: View {
    let notify = NotificationHandler()
    @State private var enablePushNotifications = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Notifications")) {
                    let toggle = Binding<Bool> (
                        get: { self.enablePushNotifications }
                        set: { newValue in
                            self.enablePushNotifications = newValue
                            })

                    Toggle("Push Notifications", isOn: toggle)
             }
        }
    }
}


Note, NavigationView is deprecated, you should use NavigationStack.
Why not use enablePushNotifications directly, eg Toggle("Push Notifications", isOn: $enablePushNotifications).

Thank you! I was out of the loop on the deprecation. I've updated to use NavigationStack.

You cannot programmatically "unauthorised" yourself from notifications, so I assume you have a flag stored in @AppStorage or somewhere else that indicates whether the user prefers to have notifications.
@AppStorage("notifications") var shouldSendNotifications = true

Only when shouldSendNotifications is true and the user has authorised your app, should you send notifications.
Then, all you need to do is to get the current authorisation status using notificationSettings, and update some @State with the status you got. You could run this code in a task(id:) block, so that you can re-run it just by changing the id.
@preconcurrency import UserNotifications

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var notificationAuthorised = false
    @State private var taskTrigger = false
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    @AppStorage("notifications") var shouldSendNotifications = true
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Notifications")) {
                let binding = Binding {
                    notificationAuthorised && shouldSendNotifications
                } set: { newValue in
                    if newValue { // turning on notifications
                        Task {
                            // perhaps also UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                            shouldSendNotifications = true

                            let notifCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
                            let settings = await notifCenter.notificationSettings()
                            if settings.authorizationStatus == .notDetermined {
                                // show the request alert
                                try await notifCenter.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge])
                            } else if settings.authorizationStatus == .denied {
                                // go to settings page
                                if let appSettings = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appSettings) {
                                    await UIApplication.shared.open(appSettings)
                                }
                            }
                            // run the task again to update notificationAuthorised
                            taskTrigger.toggle()
                        }
                    } else {
                        shouldSendNotifications = false
                        // perhaps also UIApplication.shared.unregisterForRemoteNotifications()
                    }
                }

                Toggle("Push Notifications", isOn: binding)
            }
        }
        .task(id: taskTrigger) {
            let notifCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            let settings = await notifCenter.notificationSettings()
            switch settings.authorizationStatus {
            case .notDetermined, .denied:
                notificationAuthorised = false
            case .authorized, .ephemeral, .provisional:
                notificationAuthorised = true
            @unknown default:
                notificationAuthorised = false
            }
        }
        // run the task again to update notificationAuthorised when coming back to the app
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) {
            taskTrigger.toggle()
        }
    }
}


This is exactly the type of solution I needed! My notification toggle is now versatile :)
